# User Device/Browser footprint with user working on server

Tags: angular, security, asp.net-core, fingerprinting

I'm working with angular and asp net core (api), and I would like to identify the device of the users.
But I've a problem : they're all connection to the website through a remote desktop connection to a central server, and they're all using the same browser..

Is it viable to do it with a fingerprint of browser (via fingerprintjs2 for example) ? 
Which datas should I use ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If all users are effectively using the same client, then there's no way to identify them individually via that client, obviously. In general, browser fingerprinting is not reliable anyways. It's used by analytics suites because there's not much other option for them. ("Hello user. Would you please create an account with my analytics provider so they can better track you? Please and thank you.")

When it comes to your own app, if you want to identity a user, then deploy authentication. Make the user sign into an account, and then you'll know *exactly* who they are. Nothing else will suffice.

Comment: You didn't really understand my need.
I want to identify the device of the user, not the user.

Users are already authenticated, but I would like to know which device they're using to prompt MFA if login attempts seems like suspicious.

Comment: If they're all connecting via RDP into the same box, all the site knows is the box. Or, more appropriately, all you can fingerprint is the box itself. The server logs of RDP connections may identify a device, but that's all you've got.